# The look and feel of this SE site (Propose making the most the text darker)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, css

Just to start with a positive note, the questions on this site seem to have increased in quality so I thank you for all your hard work promoting it.  Now to the negatives.  The font color on the site and the 'frammed' color background leave a lot to be desired.  Nearly all fonts used are a faded grey (SIMILAR QUESTIONS, UP-VOTES, NUMBER OF ANSWERS, QUESTION TEXT, ANSWER-TEXT) and are hard to read or look de-emphasized for some reason. Thank you for the great job and please take this as constructive criticism.

Per request I am putting a picture with the de-emphasized areas circled in red.

Comment: This would be much easier to understand with some screenshots of which parts you mean, and preferably some CSS hacks to show us how you would prefer it to look (it will be helpful both for us who read your post, and for the SE design team who would implement any feature-request). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think my firewall keeps me from uploading.  I will do so from home tonight.